# how to set internals of a class

Tags: c++, c

Hi I am pretty new to C++ and im converting C code to C++. I started by converting all the structs to classes, and added accessors and mutators for the internals, but some structs have other structs inside them. I want to know the best method for setting the internals of a class within a class, such as
    struct1.struct2.struct3.i = 5; 
where i is an int. Should I be passing as reference using accessors? but seeing as accessors tend to be const would this be something I should do?

something like
class1.get_class2().get_class3().set_i(5) or something if it can be done in this kind of format.

This is probably a dumb question but i have no idea how to do it, Thank You

Comment: `I started by converting all the structs to classes` That was fairly pointless, I'm afraid.

Comment: `C++` is not `java`. Adding accessors for every single method is not considered good style in `C++`; is usually just a lot of work, and bloats your header files. It might even make your program slower, though most compilers that support link time optimization will probably optimize them away. Other than in `java`, making most of your class members public is not considered a crime.

Comment: @mic_e I wouldn't go as far as saying it's a bad style in C++. Trying to carry over techniques from other languages isn't always good, but it's consistency which is most important to good C++ code.

Comment: I realize that it is not considered good style, but the code i'm trying to convert is relatively large and I wasn't sure which ones are actually used, so I was planning on getting rid of some when I know which ones aren't used. Thank You for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 class1.get_class2().get_class3().set_i(5)
```

is possible if `get_class2()` is non-`const` and returns a non-`const` <s>pointer</s> reference.

However, this approach completely breaks the encapsulation. The users of `class1` should not (and must not) know that `class1` uses `class2` inside and that in turn uses `class3` inside.

If a setter-API is absolutely necessary, then a better approach is do it hierarchically. For example

```
// User
class1.set_i( 5 );

// class1
class1::set_i( int x ) { class2_obj.set_i( x ); }

// class2
class2::set_i( int x ) { class3_obj.set_i( x ); }

// class3
class3::set_i( int x ) { i_ = x; }
```

Comment: I think that instead of `pointer`, you wanted to write `reference`.

Comment: this is what i ended up doing, but i wanted to know what the recommended method for converting something like struct1.struct2.struct3.i = 5, would be. thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure about that ... did you put a class inside a class or an object inside a class ?

something like :

```
class OBJ1
        {
          //methods , and other stuff
           }

class OBJ2
        {
          public OBJ1 *O ;
           }
```

is valid , so you can acces a method like :

```
OBJ2 *N2 ;
N2->O->some_method();
```

however , something like

```
class OBJ2
{
     class OBJ1;
 }
```

is not valid :P

again... not sure if this is exactly what you asked ...

Comment: it was something like                                                     `class OBJ2{                                                             public:                                                                        //accessors                                                                                                                  //mutators                                                                         private:                                                                         OBJ1 obj1                                                                        }`

Comment: sorry for messyness, not used to the format but OBJ1 obj1 is supposed to be on 1 line

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** have a good reason to access your member object via getters and setters, you can do the following:

```
class A {
public:
    void f() const {}
};

class B {
public:
    const A &get_a() const {
        // the returned reference will be read-only, i.e. only non-const member
        // functions can be called, and public members can not be written.
        // it needs to be stored in a const A & object.

        return a;
    }

    A &get_writable_a() {
        return a;
    }

    void set_a(A &a) {
        //make sure that the assignment operator of A will take care of all the
        //dirty internals, such as internal buffers that need to be deleted.
        this->a = a;
    }

private:
    //the member
    A a;
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.get_a().f();
}
```

If you **don't** have a good reason to do so, I'd recommend to simply make it a public member, and access it directy:

```
class A {
public:
    void f() const {}
};

class B {
public:
    A a;
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.a.f();
}
```

Isn't that simply much more elegant?

Note that you can use `friend` to specify other functions or classes that are allowed to directly access your private members.

As was also pointed out in an other answer, in most cases it is a bad idea to make a member object visible to the outside at all.

Comment: The `get_writable_a()` method can just be called `get_a()`.  The compiler will resolve a `get_a()` call to either the `const` or non-`const` version of the function depending on whether you're calling it on a `const` instance.

Comment: @Wyzard: Indeed, but that would make the read-only getter relatively pointless. I imagine that someone who needs getters and setters will want to explicitly force a read-only reference. Else, `b.get_a.f()` will compile without error even if `f` is non-`const`.

Comment: If you have a `const` instance, you can only call the read-only getter regardless of what it's called.  If you have a non-`const` instance, you're able to get a non-`const` reference out of it.  If you want a `const` reference anyway, just do `A const &foo = instance.get_a()` and it doesn't matter whether `get_a` returns a non-`const` reference.  It's less mental burden on the programmer if the function name is the same either way, and the constness of the result is the same as the constness of the object you call it on.